# NavigationController UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, uitextfield

I have a programatically created `UITextField` added to the `NavigationController` as below (within a `UITableViewController` since I wanted a custom fixed search bar at the top).

In .h file

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField *searchText;
```

In .m file

```
    @synthesize searchText;
    self.searchText = [[UITextField alloc] init];
    self.searchText.frame = CGRectMake(35, 234, 250, 27);
    self.searchText.backgroundColor = Rgb2UIColor(255, 255, 255);
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:self.searchText];
    self.searchText.delegate = self;
```

However none of the following methods get triggered

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
}

-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    self.searchText.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeySearch;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
}
```

Can someone point me to the right direction on why my delegate does not work?

Comment: Are you showing us ViewController or NavigationController subclass?

Comment: .m file is a ViewController (UITableViewController), should they be defined in the NavigationController?

Comment: This code looks weird (@synthesize line). Could you be more precise and show full code for header file and implementation file of your UITableViewController? Could you also write what exactly do you have in your UINavigationController subclass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better use uiseachbar from the objects panel. This comes with default search bar style and effects but is similar to uitextfield. You can set the delegate and listen to it the same way as you do for textview.

Comment: Hope that helps, anyways let me know if something goes wrong. Actually, i have implemented this feature myself. My suggestion is if you can, stick with Apples standard interface because it reduces lots of pain and its quick development too.